# SQL join data from two tables with multiple data from one table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, the first one is set up like this:

```
name(PK), height, width, age
```

The second tables is set up like this:

```
name1, name2
```

How would I go about joining the two tables two eachother to output the data in the following way:

```
name1, name2, height1, height2, width1, width2, age1, age2
```

name in the first table can be joined on to name in the second table.

Comment: Well, what is the relationship to PK(name) from one table, and the second table?  Please show sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could place table1 (with name, height, width, age values in each row) into the query twice with different alias names.  I'm sure an analysis of performance would be in order as well as possible outer joins to both table1 references (t11 and t12) in case the name1 or name2 values in table2 (t2) do not exist in table1 (t11 and t12).

```
SELECT
  t2.name1, 
  t2.name2, 
  t11.height height1, 
  t12.height height2, 
  t11.width width1,
  t12.width width2,
  t11.age age1,
  t12.age age2
FROM
  table2 t2,  -- contains rows with name1, name2
  table1 t11, -- contains rows with name, height, width, age
  table1 t12  -- contains same rows as t11 with name, height, width, age
WHERE t12.name = t2.name2 
  AND t11.name = t2.name1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that worked for me.

```
SELECT 
table2.name1, table2.name2,
t1.height as 'name1_height',
t2.height as 'name2_height',
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 on (table1.name1 = t1.name)
INNER JOIN table1 t2 on (table1.name2 = t2.name)
```